# Create a new column using a condition from other two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, lambda

I'm trying to create a column as I detailed in the next lines of code where if there is a zero value in one of the rows of the dataframe create a 'Sin Valor' value in the row of the new column of this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Qu1' : [12,34,0,45,0],
        'Qu2' : ['A1','A2',"B0",'C2','B0'],
        'Control' : ['A1', 'A2','Sin Valor/ -' + "B0" ,'C2','Sin Valor/ -'+ "B0"]})
```

In Excel, what I am trying to do should be something like this picture attached.

[image]

I was trying to create a function to do that and applying via lambda function but this isn´t working.

```
def fill_df(x):
    if data["Qu1"] == 0:
        return x.zfill('Sin Valor/ -')
    else: 
        return ' '
```

```
data['Control'] = data.apply(fill_df)
```

Is it possible to do that ? Every help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use np.where to accomplish it

```
df['ctrl'] = np.where(df['Qu1'] == 0,
                     'Sin Valor/-'+df['Qu2'],
                     df['Qu2'])
df
```

I introduced 'ctrl' column, that meets your requirement and matches 'control' (desired) column

```
    Qu1     Qu2     Control         ctrl
0    12     A1      A1              A1
1    34     A2      A2              A2
2     0     B0      Sin Valor/ -B0  Sin Valor/-B0
3    45     C2      C2              C2
4     0     B0      Sin Valor/ -B0  Sin Valor/-B0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['Qu1'] == 0
df.loc[mask, 'Control'] = 'Sin Valor/ -' + df['Qu2'][mask]
```